# How to reduce the size of mp3s in linux?

Tags: linux, mp3, filesize

Does anyone know of any linux software to reduce the size of mp3 files while having a minimal effect on quality?

I just used pngcrush to do this to all the pngs in our asset library with good results, and would love to be able to do the same to our mp3s.  Even if there is a 10% reduction in file size that would be a decent win for me.

Any suggestions?  It needs to be something i can call from a shell script.

cheers, max

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `lame` with the `--mp3input` option.

For example you can do a `downsampling` of the mp3 quality, specifing the a new lower `bitrate` using the `-b` option. For example if your starting mp3 has a quality of `256kbs` you can lower it's bitrate to `128kbs`:

```
lame --mp3input -b 128 input.mp3 output.mp3
```

Depending from the input file bitrate, the `output.mp3` file has lower quality and so a file size reduction.

From the `lame` manuale page:

> `--mp3input`
>                 Assume the input file is a MP3 file.
>                 Useful for downsampling from one mp3 to another.  As an example, it can be useful for    streaming  through  an  IceCast
>                 server.

Comment: Worth noting, you may want to explicitly re-sample, eg `--resample 22.05` which is often fine for voice. eg:

`mkdir out ; for f in *.mp3 ; do lame --mp3input -b 64 --resample 22.50 "$f" "out/$f" ; done`

Comment: Looking for another solution. `lame` is problematic and fails on random files that otherwise play perfectly using `mplayer`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve. *avconv* (formerly *ffmpeg*) is a good tool, but there's no one size fits all solution pertaining the parameters, since it depends heavily on the type of audio data (music, speech, etc) and the original bitrate, etc. Try the different settings, maybe *convert it to mono*, see what produces still acceptable results for you.

As a general rule of thumb: Speech compresses really well, downsampling it to 11kHz may still give acceptable results, but music can also be downsized by decreasing the bitrate or switching to mono.

Comment: Great tip about speech, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). It's a free audio editing program

Comment: It needs to be scriptable.  I have audacity but i don't think you can use it purely as a command line tool can you?

Comment: Try using avconv (ffmpeg) for scriptability.